# UIPanGestureRecognizer fails to enter .ended state after screen rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having an issue with handling screen rotations when a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is in the `.changed` state. My handling logic looks something like:

```
@objc fileprivate func handlePanGesture() {
    let state = self.panGestureRecognizer.state
    if state == .began {
        // Log beginning state
    } else if state == .changed {
        // Track position, update constraints
    } else if state == .ended {
        // Reset and prepare for new gesture
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working well, but when the device is rotated to a new orientation (without lifting my finger), the gesture recognizer stops receiving updates for the active touch, but never triggers the `handlePanGesture()` with the `.ended` state set.

Right now I'm handling this by looking out for `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` and cleaning up the state when that happens, but this approach fails when, e.g., an iPad is rotated from portrait-right-side-up to portrait-upside-down--there is never any size transition. Is there something that can be done to cancel the gesture recognizer on rotation (and trigger a call to `handlePanGesture()`)?

Comment: I don't have an iPad to test but will `viewWillTransition` not be called at all in case of the rotation case you mentioned ? I am genuinely asking not questioning your point.

Comment: Did you check the `.cancelled` state?

Comment: @rmaddy D’oh, I thought I had read some documentation that said the action was only called on `.began`, `.changed`, and `.ended`, but looking back now it seems like I was mistaken... will verify tomorrow that that’s the answer but seems promising. Thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: @MayRestinPeace From my testing, no it will not. I don't know if that's a guarantee, but it looks like that method really is only called when the size will actually change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to check for the `.cancelled` state.

btw, switch on the state rather than if, else if, else if, else if

Comment: Yeah, as noted in the comments it was just forgetting the `.cancelled` state :) As far as `switch`/`if else`, I prefer the latter here since I don't want to make the `switch` exhaustive when there are values that `state` will never take on in this function.